# how to get customer order count for all customers in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, collection

I Tried this and it is working but i can only do for a specific customer but i need this for all customer.

```
<?php
$customer_id = 5;
$_orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$customer_id);                        
$_orderCnt = $_orders->count(); //orders count
echo 'Customer with ID '.$customer_id.' has '.$_orderCnt.' orders';
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use below code:

```
<?php
   $customerCollection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
      ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id');

   foreach($customerCollection as $customer){
      $_orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$customer->getId());                        
      $_orderCnt = $_orders->count(); //orders count
      echo 'Customer with ID '.$customer_id.' has '.$_orderCnt.' orders';
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to get customer collection. You can iterate through collections. The code for interator can be found in this post

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786826/how-to-loop-a-magento-collection

Once you have iterator in place you need to dynamically get each customer id and pass it into your filter.

Answer (score 2):

use group by to group them on basis of customer id and then get count from it..
you can use group by on your collection like this :
`$collection->getSelect()->group('table_name.entityname');`